# Is it safe to use OAuth authorization code flow tokens from the client JS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm reading through the Spotify Web API documentation, focusing on the authorization guides.
They provide some example code for the **authorization code** OAuth2 flow, but there is something that doesn't seem quite right to me. My knowledge about the OAuth protocol is a bit limited, so I cannot be sure about this.

The fact is that they make the call to obtain the access and refresh tokens on the server side, but then they do a redirect to the initial route **passing the tokens as URL parameters, to allow use from the JS code**.
Here is the code of the node.js server:

```
[POST call to the token end-point to get the tokens]

[...]

// we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
res.redirect('/#' +
    querystring.stringify({
        access_token: access_token,
        refresh_token: refresh_token
    })
);
```

Then, on the front-end JS, they make HTTP requests to the API using those tokens. They even do token refresh as an AJAX call.

My question is: isn't this a bad way of using the authorization code flow? Sould I modify the code and migrate all the API calls that require the use of the access token to the back-end, and then get the received informations via internal calls to the back-end?

Comment: According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.2 you should use Implicit grant

Comment: Unless there is a specific design requirement, do NOT send OAuth tokens from the server to the client. Use sessions / cookies. Sessions / cookies should be encrypted or be opaque. Do not send the Refresh Token to the client. Almost always use three-legged OAuth.  Almost always never trust the browser or client. The details depend on what you need from Authentication, Authorization and Identification to safely provide services to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on your application. If your user uses your website and trusts his browser, keeping the tokens on the browser should not be a problem. Saving a token as a cookie on the browser is then security wise the same as that user being logged into your own login mechanism that allows the user to use your api.

Migrating it so that your client asks the server to perform actions means that you need to have a few things:

- A server that serves the request (maybe you just want a webapp doing the OAuth, with no backend)
- The user needs to trust your server that you keep the token safe
- Some form of authorization to make sure only that one user can use your api and with it the token
- Your server needs to serve additional requests and is an additional delay for each request

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry if I haven't been clear enough. Supposing that the application **doesn't provide a login mechanism**, it just uses OAuth to let the user authorize it to access their Spotify data, then it would be ok to use the token on the client side? Like @John is saying, I should only set it as a cookie instead of passing it as a query parameter, right? If I understand correctly, SSL is enough to protect against any possible vulnerability.

Comment: Also, speaking about the second case, there shouldn't be any problem in doing every call to the resource server API from the back-end. What do you mean by "The user needs to trust your server that you keep the token safe"? Should I implement an authentication and user login functionality?

Comment: If your application has no login mechanism at all, I would suggest you keep the token on the client and do all requests to the spotify api on the client too. If you can, don't save the cookie anywhere. If you must save it, give users a way to log out. Keeping a token save is if you store tokens on your server. That is basically like a password to their account, so you don't want to just have it somewhere unsafe.